# Creating a page for languages in joomla

Tags: php, internationalization, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Is there any extension for joomla that could generate a page which includes a link to translate the website to a specific language?

it's going to be a basic page something similar to this link http://www.trekbikes.com/worldwide that when a new language is added on joomla the it's automatically added on the page as well.

Comment: To clarify, will you be preparing the various language translations manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a solution to this problem what I did is I have created an article then added this code below:

```
{loadposition language}
```

on the content body then I override the language switcher module and made the necessary updates to make it work. :)